# Как исправить ошибку в Delphi:Lookup information for field '' is incomplete

Tags: база-данных, delphi, access

В после создания поля с подстановкой, при запуске возникает ошибка: Lookup information for field 'Napr' is incomplete. (Все формы связал между собой*)

Есть 2 таблицы:
1)Вакансии (находится на первой форме)
2)Направление (находится на второй форме)
из т.Направление я беру код.Направления и подставляю в результат поле "Имя"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле в итоге подставляется, но при запуске ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересно то, что ошибки нет в случае, когда обе таблицы находятся на форме.
Но в моём случае таблицы находятся на разных формах.

Comment: Подключение к БД выполняется вручную по кнопке или при загрузке формы? Вообще для этого существуют DataModule, на которые кладутся все нужные DB-компоненты, а потом оттуда уже подключаются куда надо. И в свойствах проекта необходимо убедиться что дата-модуль создаётся раньше этих форм.